post_filter after applying top_hits aggregation not working in elastic search
Expectation:
I need all users which are not successful in their last attempt.
Actual/My Approach:
I applied aggregation by userId and top_hits with size of 1 document which is sorted in descending order of the time.
I have prepared the query like this. Through this I am able to get all users and their last status. After that I want to filter based on status. Can any one help here in fixing this. I have applied post_filter after aggregation, but still its not filtering.
In case of any other approach, please help here.
Input:
[
  {
    "userId": "u1",
    "status": "Failure",
    "time": 1719543600008 // This is most updated record for user - u1
  },
  {
    "userId": "u1",
    "status": "Success",
    "time": 1719543600007
  },
  {
    "userId": "u1",
    "status": "Timeout",
    "time": 1719543600006
  },
  {
    "userId": "u2",
    "status": "Timeout",
    "time": 1719543600004 // This is most updated record for user - u2
  },
  {
    "userId": "u2",
    "status": "Failure",
    "time": 1719543600003
  },
  {
    "userId": "u3",
    "status": "Success",
    "time": 1719543600002 // This is most updated record for user - u3. As its success, it needs to be discarded from output
  },
  {
    "userId": "u3",
    "status": "Failure",
    "time": 1719543600001
  }
]

Expected Output:
[
  {
    "userId": "u1",
    "status": "Failure",
    "time": 1719543600008
  },
  {
    "userId": "u2",
    "status": "Timeout",
    "time": 1719543600004
  }
]

Query:
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "data.time": {
              "gte": "1719543600000",
              "lte": "1719584179015",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "data.type:\"user-stats\""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_userId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "data.userId.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "users_last_status": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "data.time": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": { // In this query this filter is not working
    "term": {
      "data.status.keyword": "failure"
    }
  }
}


Actual Output:
[
  {
    "userId": "u1",
    "status": "Failure",
    "time": 1719543600008
  },
  {
    "userId": "u2",
    "status": "Timeout",
    "time": 1719543600004
  },
  {
    "userId": "u3", // This shouldn't come in output as we are concerned about only failure records.
    "status": "Success",
    "time": 1719543600002 
  }
]

Note:
As there is no limit on number of users, we don't want to filter on application/client side to reduce load.

post_filter only affects the query results and not the aggregations results.

Use the search API’s post_filter parameter. Search requests apply post
filters only to search hits, not aggregations. You can use a post
filter to calculate aggregations based on a broader result set, and
then further narrow the results.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html

You can use terms query in the query.bool.filter like the following.
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {"range":{"data.time":{"gte":"1719543600000","lte":"1719584179015","format":"epoch_millis"}}},
        {"query_string":{"query":"data.type:\"user-stats\""}},
        {"terms":{"status":["Timeout","Failure"]}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {...}
}


If we filter before aggregating users, then we will not get final status of each user.
If you check the expected output, we don't  need the user-3
{
"userId": "u3", // This shouldn't come in output as we are concerned about only failure records in their last attempt
"status": "Success",
"time": 1719543600002
}

Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand your use case. Yes you're right we can't filter before aggs. Filtering on client side is the best option but because you don't prefer that you can check the bucket selector aggs. It will help you to filter the aggregation results.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html

Looks like only boolean and number fields can be filtered through bucket selector.
Can you please help here for comparing strings

When trying to filter for any string, getting below exception.
buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [StringTerms] at aggregation
